# SQL - INFORMATION_SCHEMA for All Databases On Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` work for only specified databases.

Is it possible to query table metadata for ALL databases on server by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: Do you have proper access right with your user which makes the queries?

Comment: Assuming I have, what would the solution be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this only by using dynamic query for database iteration. One way is using **ms_ForEachDB** stored procedure, second is querying **sys.databases** dynamic view.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding Dalex's answer into code.

```
--Make sure you have a global temporary table to use. Double dots are shorthand for .dbo.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##test
--Create the table definition the easy way.
SELECT * INTO ##test
FROM ???.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES --The ??? will be whatever the name of your first database is.
DELETE FROM ##test
--Add all the data.
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? INSERT INTO ##test SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
--View all the data.
SELECT * FROM ##test
--Clean up.
DROP TABLE ##test
```

Answer (score 4):

Modified [Dustin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5799992/dustin-morrison) code (from [Dalex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544428/dalex)'s suggestion) to accommodate database names with spaces and eliminate common system tables from results.

```
--Make sure you have a global temporary table to use. Double dots are shorthand for .dbo.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##test

--Create the table definition the easy way.
SELECT top 1 * INTO ##test
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
DELETE FROM ##test

--Add all the data.
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?] INSERT INTO ##test SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'

--View all the data.
SELECT * FROM ##test
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG NOT IN ('master','tempdb', 'msdb')
ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME

--Clean up.
DROP TABLE ##test
```

Comment: Are those common system tables related to particular vendors? If so, which for which?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM information_schema.tables
group by tables.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.
In particular, does this grab all databases' metadata at once?  AIUI (based on MyQSL and PostgreSQL) that will return table metadata only for the current database.  Is SQL Server different in that regard?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The query provided only returns data for the current database context. If you have multiple databases (TABLE_CATALOG) on your server then it doesn't show all of them, which is what this question asked for.  Try this `SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_CATALOG FROM information_schema.tables` and you will only see one value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to the question but this text adds context ... and text is likely to be useful to someone to gain understanding.

It is possible and often required to add a use clause to select which database is being referenced above the select clause ..

e.g.

```
use CaseData

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns 

--WHERE 

--TABLE_CATALOG = 'CaseData'

--and TABLE_SCHEMA ='Clinical'

--and 

--TABLE_NAME = 'SAASCaseData_NewFieldsOct2018'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `TABLE_SCHEMA` FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`;
```

Comment: The question itself states that this does not work. In SQL Server the query above returns schema for the database that the query is being run under only and does not run across databases.