# How to find all tables and datasets/databases which have a specific column name in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

I want to find a specific column name across all tables across all datasets/databases in Big Query.

In Teradata it can be done by running the following:

```
SELECT 
    DatabaseName, 
    TableName, 
    ColumnName 
FROM 
    DBC.Columns 
WHERE 
    ColumnName LIKE '%sender_country%' 
    AND DatabaseName NOT LIKE '%test%' 
    AND tablename LIKE '%sender%'
```

How can the same thing done be in Big Query?

I know we can look for different columns inside a particular dataset by running the following:

```
SELECT
    ddl 
FROM
    project-name.my_database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 
    table_name like '%sender%' 
    AND ddl LIKE '%sender_country%'
```

But the above query limits the search to only one dataset/database (in this example `my_database_name`).

How do I extend the search across all datasets?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787212/sql-information-schema-for-all-databases-on-server does answer ?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is per database. The only way is multiple queries, dynamic sql, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution is to replace the dataset name with `region-us` instead.

The below works for looking up across tables and datasets

```
SELECT
    ddl 
FROM
    `project-name`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE 
    table_name like '%sender%' 
    AND ddl LIKE '%sender_country%'
```

The below works for views:

```
SELECT
    ddl 
FROM
    `project-name`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE 
    table_name like '%sender%' 
    AND ddl LIKE '%sender_country%'
```